# jquery get function with link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, get, href

I have some link with parameter:

```
<a href="index.php?page=home&lang=en" class="flag">
    <img src="./images/flags/en.png" class="flag_on" alt="en" title="en">
</a>
```

and how to parse **$lang** parameter to index.php by clicking on link with jQuery/Ajax ?

**My working example:**

```
$(".flag").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, function(data) {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're trying to get the query string `lang` parameter from the `a` tag when you click on the image?

Comment: @Tejs: I click on link. It will redirect to `index.php?page=home&lang=en`. Then in index.php I have `$_GET['lang']` to manage that parameter.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @asawyer - Me neither, what's the point here, what's supposed to be parsed, the PHP variable $lang or is the point to insert the right href in the $.get function, like many of the answers do ?

Comment: @adeneo: php variable `$lang` parsing to index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".flag_on").click(function(){
    $.get($(this).parent().attr("href"), function(data) {
         $('.result').html(data);
         alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});​
```

Or you can modify HTML code to use click event for the link but not for the image:

```
<a href="index.php?page=home&lang=en" class="flag">
    <img src="./images/flags/en.png" class="flag_on" alt="en" title="en">
</a>

$(".flag").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Second option might work. Can you change script to reload page 1 time to see changes? Delete alert and insert page reload.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you wish to get. If you use Ajax to update some content on the page without reloading, then `$('.result').html(data)` suits perfectly. If you wish to update the whole page with Ajax then you can simply update body with `$('body').html(data)`. However, if you wish to reload page, you don't need Ajax at all, simple click on the link will update your page, if your PHP script is tuned for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request the same url then just try this. There is no need to parse the querystring params and create the same url.

```
$(".flag_on").click(function(e){
    $.get(this.parent()[0].href, function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    e.stopPropagation(); //stop event bubbling
});
```

Comment: since the class is on the img element that won't work, he needs to target the parent element

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the href of the anchor in your get request. something like

```
var target_url =$(this).parent("a") 
$.get(target_url, function(data){
  do something...
}
```

you can then also parse target_url to get the params as well